# MySQL databse/schema

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to connect to a database in php it makes me use the schema I created for the DB instead of the db itself.

Also, if I decide to use a different schema I have to change it in the terminal mysql. When I use the line "show databases;" it only shows the schemas created

Is this how it is supposed to be, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you create the DB before creating the schema?

Comment: yes, I created db first

Comment: If you used mysql via terminal then I think first you do select the database, which you want. like ...
use restaurant
In the case restaurant is my db name. Now you select your own database and work with it. I hope its fine.